# Discord.js client.on guildMemberAdd firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

As the title explains, I have a function in my Discord.js (v12) bot that takes care of welcoming users and assigning them a specific role. Here's the code:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    member.roles.add('604250195001081859');
    member.guild.channels.cache.get("707323130523418686").send(`Hi ${member.user} blabla`);
    console.log(member.user.id + ' is in da house');
});
```

Now, I'm facing a problem: every time someone joins the server, it seems like this event is triggered multiple times, flooding the channel.

Obviously, this doesn't happen if I use "client.once," but in that case, the message is only sent to the user on their first access, and subsequent users don't receive it.

I've searched everywhere for answers, but it seems like I'm the only one experiencing this issue. I hope someone can help me.

P.S.
I want to clarify that I don't have any other active instances of the bot, and it is hosted on a small Vultr VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I managed to find the problem. If you encounter this issue, please check your entire project to locate this method call:

```
client.login(<token>)
```

If it's called within a keepalive function or, in any case, within a function that is called multiple times after or outside the server startup, it creates a new instance of the bot. Each instance will respond to events, resulting in a flood of messages (in the case of chat messages) or the repetition of any operation inside the function for each created instance.

In summary, the `login()` method only needs to be called once to prevent the creation of new instances.

And yes, you can now throw all the rotten tomatoes at me if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me a lot go to the discord dev portal and generate a new token and paste the new token into your code. For some reason its running multiple instances of your bot at the same time and generating a new token should fix that issue. I know you said you dont have multiple instances running but you will not be able to see the instances, its a weird bug.

Comment: Ok so... i've tried to do what you say... in first instace seems working, but after a couple of days, one guy join the server and the flood are happened again.

Your solution seems not working for me :(

Comment: Add me on discord:ItIsN3RD#4113 and can you send me your code through discord so I can take a look at it. Did you make any changes to your code and restart your bot since you generated new tokens?

Comment: I add you i'm Nerdomante#4529, however i didn't make any changes and restart the bot (also because if i don't do it, doesn't take the changes, it started with forever module)